# How do I create a validation rule on a QTY field if more than 2 and then a Box must be checked?

Tags: validation-rule, checkbox

I have a quantity field "Product Qty"
When Product is Greater than 2, a checkbox "Conditional PO" must be checked. 
Below validation rule isn't working.  Can you help?

```
AND(
VALUE(TEXT(Product_Qty__c)) <= 1)
Conditional_PO_Required__c  = FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this as

```
AND(
VALUE(TEXT(Product_Qty__c)) > 2,
Conditional_PO_Required__c  = FALSE )
```

Remember that a validation rule fires (i.e. stops a record saving) when the result is `true`.

Comment: I tried and received an Error: Syntax error. Extra ','

Comment: @JT2016 I save this in my org with changed field, Can you please confirm you have save exact value.

Comment: Your recommendation worked.  Thank you so much for your quick response.